# Wifi Direct: One to Many

Tags: android, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I am developing an offline quiz application with one user as host and other users as participants. I am trying to use Wi-Fi Direct to communicated between devices. I am able to communicated between one to one devices using example [1](https://github.com/deib-polimi/PigeonMessanger) and [2](https://github.com/bastianmorath/P2P-Chat-Application). Now I want to make communication between one to many with one Device as host and other devices as participants.